# Will an unknown or missing DKIM, SPF, or DMARC parameter always cause an email to be marked as spam?

Tags: email, spam-prevention

I recently found that an email provider I use is unable to send email to some popular systems like aol.com, verizon.net, (and perhaps others) without being marked as Spam. I became suspicious after months of several emails going unanswered even though they had answered in the past. I eventually found that many of my emails were being immediately redirected to an online Spam folder on these receiving systems. Depending on how the recipient retrieves their email the Spam folder with the accumulated emails might never be seen.

Initially I contacted the support group at my email provider. They generated a ticket to investigate the issue. A few days later they came back stating that there were no problems with their system that it must be an issue at the recipients end, therefore there was nothing they could do.

I was able to obtain access to two email systems where my emails were being marked as spam. Looking into the properties of my emails I found that the DKIM and sometimes the DMARC parameters were listed as "Unknown". On some older emails (that passed to the inbox) the DKIM had been listed as "Pass" while the DMARC was sometimes listed as “NULL”.

I also found that if a user is able to directly access AOL's online email system it is possible to eventually find the online spam folder and manually mark an email as "Not Spam". This then allows that email and all later email from that sender to pass to the online inbox and finally to the user’s other email devices.  While this is somewhat of a work-around solution actually calling all my current email contacts and explaining how to do something like this is ridicules.

So how important are the DKIM, SPF, and DMARC parameters in modern email exchanges? If one of them is missing or comes up "Unknown" is that a potential reason for a private email to be marked as spam? Is it easy enough for an email provider to correctly set up these parameters to satisfy other popular email systems?

Comment: pretty important. as you have noted a number of big email providers have decided to enforce DMARC, based on whether the message has appropriate DKIM/SPF validation. DMARC leaves the recommendation for emails that fail DKIM/SPF to the controller of the domain, so the provider can decide what to do when it gets a response of "enforce" or "reject". it is completely up to them, and you have absolutely no control over the situation, other than to ensure that your messages pass DMARC most of the time by using reliable email services and making sure they are properly configured.

Comment: `So how important are the DKIM, SPF, and DMARC parameters in modern email exchanges?` Quite important if you don't want to be marked as spam.   `If one of them is missing or comes up "Unknown" is that a potential reason for a private email to be marked as spam?` In combination with other factors, check SpamAssassin rules     `Is it easy enough for an email provider to correctly set up these parameters to satisfy other popular email systems?` It is their job. And it is not difficult.

Comment: Try https://www.mail-tester.com/ it helps identify problems for free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing black and white here - email delivery is nuanced and SPF, DKIM, DMARC are only a fairly small part of the equation, assuming these are not explicitly set up so as to instruct recipient servers to reject email.

I expect the reputation of your smtp provider and the content of your messages play a much bigger role then yourcSOF, DKIM and DMARC settings.  Lots  of domains dont have any if these set and most emails work just fine.

Comment: as I understand it, its all about where the domains MX records point. the MX server is by default authoritative, so DMARC isn't a consideration for an org sending its own email on its own domain. DMARC come in when service providers that are not necessarily trusted MX servers for that domain are sending email on behalf of it (for instance if your org uses salesforce, and sends emails on behalf of your domain; you would not want to let another salesforce customer send emails from your domain, even if they came from that server).  dmarc is a way to authenticate remote servers to clients.

Comment: @FrankThomas My understanding is quite different. MX servers are not, by default, authorative for anything other then receiving email.  I think much of three functionality you attribute to DMARC is done with SPF. DMARC conveys to recipient servers how the sender would like emails with DKIM or SPF issues to be handled.